# Is there a construction which multiplies and adds spanning trees in Logspace?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, planar-graphs, logspace, determinant, spanning-tree

I.1 Suppose we have two planar graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ with spanning tree count $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively then is there a graph construction in Logspace to get a planar graph from $G_1$ and $G_2$ with spanning tree count $C_1C_2$ without knowing $C_1$ or $C_2$?

I.2 How about if we are allowed to know $C_2$ alone?

II.1 Suppose we have two planar graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ with spanning tree count $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively then is there a graph construction in Logspace to get a planar graph from $G_1$ and $G_2$ with spanning tree count $C_1+C_2$ without knowing $C_1$ or $C_2$?

II.2 How about if we are allowed to know $C_2$ alone?

For properness assume the number of spanning tress is at least $3$ in $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Comment: I gather you assume the graphs to be connected.

Comment: $C_1C_2$ is obvious: just take the disjoint union of the two graphs, and connect them by one edge (no matter which one).

Comment: Do you know of any procedure which accomplishes II.1? For starters, does a planar graph with spanning tree count $C$ exist for every $C$, having size polynomial in $\log C$?

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen I do not know.